# Libgdx Sound | setPitch causes Sound object to stop playing/making noise

Tags: android, libgdx

I have a Sound object that calls setPitch(id, 1.0f). For some reason, on most devices this seems to work and sound perfect (I realize that 1.0f is normal). But on the galaxy note 3, it makes an ugly deep sound, then the Sound object no longer makes any sounds after calling play method again (I play the Sound object every time player gets point). Setting pitch is necessary because I use the same Sound object for other parts of my game. I will link my code below, but I feel as though this may be a libgdx glitch/hardware problem. Thanks!

```
if (contact.getFixtureA().getFilterData().categoryBits == Config.CATEGORYBIT_BONUS) {
    final BonusFixtureUserData userData = (BonusFixtureUserData) contact.getFixtureA().getUserData();
    if (userData.bonus.scorable) {               
        long id = AudioManager.getAudioManager().playSound(AudioManager.getAudioManager().bonusSound);
        AudioManager.getAudioManager().bonusSound.setPitch(id, Config.pointSoundPitch * 2);
    }
}
```

AudioManager class (below)

```
public class AudioManager {

private static AudioManager audioManager;

public Sound jumpSound, deathSound, pointSound, bonusSound;

public static AudioManager getAudioManager() {
    if (audioManager == null) {
        audioManager = new AudioManager();
    }
    return audioManager;
}

private float sound_volume, music_volume;

private AudioManager() {
    sound_volume = 1f;

}

public void setAudio() {
    deathSound = (Sound) Game.assetManager.get("sound/death.mp3");
    jumpSound = (Sound) Game.assetManager.get("sound/tap.mp3");
    pointSound = (Sound) Game.assetManager.get("sound/point.mp3");
    bonusSound = (Sound) Game.assetManager.get("sound/point.mp3");
}

public long playSound(Sound sound) { //Returns soundID (Sound can play multiple times, soundID refers to which instance is playing)
    long id = sound.play();
    sound.setLooping(id, false);
    sound.setVolume(id, sound_volume);
    return id;
}

public static void dispose() {
    audioManager = null;
}

}
```

Config.pointPitchSound is actually equal to between 1.0f and 1.07f throughout the game. When it is 1.0f, then it does the glitch. I haven't tried the other values, but I would asume they'd do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX audio implementation depends completely on Android. `Sound.setPitch` actually calls `SoundPool.setRate` [Android documentation of setRate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate(int,%20float))

Try to convert sounds to OGG format, it is known that SoundPool has issues with playing MP3 files on some devices.

Comment: Unfortunately converting to ogg files didn't fix the problem :\

Comment: It appears this happens when the pitch is >= 2. Rather odd, isn't it?

Comment: Ohh it is not odd, look at the Android doc I sent. `float: playback rate (1.0 = normal playback, range 0.5 to 2.0)` I guess this is the reason.